# How do streams work..Getting error "more than operator >> matches these operands"

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm not sure how streams works as I am fairly new to c++. I have a program which is suppose to add, delete, view and update records in a file. I've added stuff to file already but having problems with the others. Your help would be most appreciated.Here is a part of my driver.cpp

```
        int main()
    {

    Mainmenu();
    return 0;
    }

     void Mainmenu()
    {
    int option;


    cout << "1: Clinic Visit\t\t";
    cout << "2: Removal\t\t";
    cout << "3: Exit Visit\t\t\n";
    cout << "Select an option\n\n\n";
    cin >> option;
    system("cls");

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:     
        Showclinic();
            break;
    case 2: //RemAnimal();

        break;
    case 3:

        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "unknown option";
    }

     } 


     void  Showclinic()
     {
    int x;
    Intervention inte;

    cout << "1: ADD\n\n";
    cout << "2: UPDATE\n\n";
    cout << "3: VIEW\n\n";
    cout << "4: VIEW ALL\n\n";
    cout << "5: DELETE\n\n";
    cout << "6: Exit\n\n";
    cout << "Enter Choice\n";
    cin >> x;
    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        cout << "CURRENTLY ADDING DATA\n";
        addVisit("JSPCA.txt", inte);

        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "UPDATE";
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "VIEW";
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 4:system("cls");
        cout << "VIEW ALL RECORDS ON FILE\n";
        ViewAll("JPSCA.txt",inte);
        system("pause");
        break;
    case 5:system("cls");
        cout << "DELETE";
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "EXIT";

        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "value of x unknown";
    }

    }
    std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, int i)
    {

   }
        //***********************************************************
     std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Intervention &i) {


    is >> i.getClient().getInterventionNo();
    is >> i.getClient().getClinic();
    is >> i.getClient().getFname();
    is >> i.getClient().getLname();
    is >> i.getClient().getPayment();
    is >> i.getAddress().getStreetNo();
    is >> i.getAddress().getStreetName();
    is >> i.getAddress().getTown();
    is >> i.getTelNo().getAreaCode();
    is >> i.getTelNo().getExchange();
    is >> i.getTelNo().getLine();
    is >> i.getAnimal().getBreed();
    is >> i.getAnimal().getType();
    is >> i.getAnimal().getGender();;
    is >> i.getAnimal().getAge();;
    is >> i.getAnimal().getProblem();;
    is >> i.getDate().getDay();
    is >> i.getDate().getMonth();;
    is >> i.getDate().getYear();
    is >> i.getTime().getHour();
    is >> i.getTime().getMin();
    //is >> endl;

    return is;
    }

    std::ostream &operator>>(std::ostream &os, Intervention  &const i) {

    os << i.getClient().getInterventionNo();
    os << i.getClient().getClinic() << "";
     os << i.getClient().getFname() << "";
    os << i.getClient().getLname() << "";
    os << i.getClient().getPayment() << "";
    os << i.getAddress().getStreetNo() << "";
    os << i.getAddress().getStreetName() << "";
    os << i.getAddress().getTown() << "";
     os << i.getTelNo().getAreaCode() << "";
    os << i.getTelNo().getExchange() << "";
     os << i.getTelNo().getLine() << "";
    os << i.getAnimal().getBreed() << "";
    os << i.getAnimal().getType() << "";
    os << i.getAnimal().getGender() << "";
     os << i.getAnimal().getAge() << "";
    os << i.getAnimal().getProblem() << "";
    os << i.getDate().getDay() << "";
    os << i.getDate().getMonth() << "";
     os << i.getDate().getYear() << "";
    os << i.getTime().getHour() << "";
    os << i.getTime().getMin() << "";
     os << endl;

    return os;
    }


      void addVisit(string name, Intervention inte)
    {
    int hour, min, day, month, yr, snum, age;
    string fname, lname, interNo, problem, clinic, area, ex, li,                      type,                    breed,sname,town, pay;

     cout << "Enter new intervention number\n";
    cin >> interNo;

    // user enters information, which is copied into file
    cout << "Enter name of clinic(Winchester or Caymanas)\n ";
    cin >> clinic;
    cout << "Enter lastname, firstname\n ";
    cin >> lname;
    cin >> fname;
    cout << "Please Address(Street#, Street Name, Town)\n";
    cin >> snum >> sname >> town;
    cout << "Enter Contact#:(area exchange line)\n";
    cin >> area >> ex >> li;
    cout << "Enter Animal Type, Breed,Gender and Age\n";
    cin >> type >> breed >> gender >> age;
    cout << "Please specify problem\n";
    cin >> problem;
    cout <<( "Please enter letter for payment type:\n");
    cout << ("Full=F\n");
    cout << ("Contribution=C\n");
    cout << ("Can't Pay=CP\n");
    cin >> pay;
    cout << "Enter date in format month dd mm yyyy\n";
    cin >> day >> month >> yr;
    cout << "Enter the time(hour minute\n)";
    cin >> hour >> min;
        // set record InterventionNo, Client,animal, date and time values
        //inte.setInterventionNo(input);
        inte.setClient(Client(fname, lname, pay,interNo,clinic));
        inte.setAddress(Address(snum, sname, town));
        inte.setTelNo(TelNo(area, ex, li));
        inte.setAnimal(Animal(type, breed, gender, age, problem));
        inte.setDate(Date(day, month, yr));
        inte.setTime(Time(hour, min));


        ofstream clientfile(name, ios::app);
        if (clientfile)
        {
            clientfile << inte.getClient().getInterventionNo() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getClient().getClinic() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getClient().getFname() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getClient().getLname() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getClient().getPayment() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAddress().getStreetNo() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAddress().getStreetName() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAddress().getTown() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getTelNo().getAreaCode() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getTelNo().getExchange() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getTelNo().getLine() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAnimal().getBreed() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAnimal().getType() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAnimal().getGender() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAnimal().getAge() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getAnimal().getProblem() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getDate().getDay() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getDate().getMonth() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getDate().getYear() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getTime().getHour() << "";
            clientfile << inte.getTime().getMin() << "";
            clientfile << endl;
            clientfile.close();
        }//end if


    else{
        cerr << "Intervention #" << interNo << " already contains information. "     << endl;
    }
    }
     //**********************************************************************
     void ViewAll(string name, Intervention inte)
     {
    std::ifstream in(name);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Intervention>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<Intervention>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<Intervention>(std::cout, "\n"));

    }
```

Comment: You can't overload it for an `int`.

Comment: I get errors for the integer values that I am trying to read when I take it out

Comment: We need more detail than this. What is not working? Are you getting errors? If so, tell us what they are. Also, this is way too much code to look through. You need to give us a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.